# Getting lookup parameters from the DoesNotExist exception instance

Tags: python, django

The [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/intro/tutorial01/) has a section showing some code with `DoesNotExist` exception being raised:

```
# Request an ID that doesn't exist, this will raise an exception.
>>> Poll.objects.get(id=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
DoesNotExist: Poll matching query does not exist. Lookup parameters were {'id': 2}
```

The message on the exception instance shows the parameters used for the lookup.  But I don't see those parameters:

```
>>> django.get_version()
'1.5.6'
>>> Client.objects.get(pk=2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
DoesNotExist: Client matching query does not exist.
```

Actually, that information would be very helpful for my projects debug logging purposes.  Why don't we see it, and how can it be turned back on if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tutorial was written for Django 1.5. At that time, the exception was more detailed, [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.5/django/db/models/query.py#L398):

```
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
          "%s matching query does not exist. "
          "Lookup parameters were %s" %
          (self.model._meta.object_name, kwargs))
```

But, in the latest versions, the exception message was changed and now contains only, [source](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/query.py#L365):

```
raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
          "%s matching query does not exist." %
          self.model._meta.object_name)
```

FYI, the actual [changeset](https://github.com/django/django/commit/266c0bb23e9d64c47ace4d162e582febd5a1e336) tried to fix [Passing self to object query may cause infinite regression](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20278) issue.